# How to create an Hive External on & delimited Key-Value pair

Tags: hive

I have a simple requirement of creating an "Hive external table" on a text file which has data in the format of

colAAA=2&colDDD=1065985&colBBB=valueBB&colCCC=875
COL_NAME=VALUE&COL_NAME=VALUE&COL_NAME=VALUE

I cannot use RegEx Serde as the column names don't come in a defined order. Is there a way to create external table with out writing a new CustomSerde ??

create external table if not exists custom_table_name(
colAAA int,
colBBB int,
colCCC string,
colDDD int)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '&'
????????????? How to make it read the Key-Value ??

I would like to avoid writing CustomSerde unless there is no open-source  SERDE available ... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create external table with one map column to parse your data

```
create external table some_table
(map_col map<string, string>)
row format 
   COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '&'
   MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '='
stored as textfile
location <your_location>
```

then select map keys of your interest

```
create table another_table as
select map_col['colAAA'] as colAAA, ...etc
  from some_table
```

Comment: just added one more property delimited fields terminated by '\t'